# How to handle associative arrays in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, associative-array, swi-prolog

I have a `Prolog` list

```
[['A1', 'I'], ['A1', 'EU'], ['A2', 'EU']]
```

that I would like to transform it into a dictionary like this one

```
{'EU':['A1','A2'], 'I':['A1']}
```

1. How do I create the prolog dictionary (I am using swipl)
2. How do access keys and values
3. How do I add/remove terms?

Comment: This "dictionary" seems to be an [associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303158/prolog-mappings-associative-arrays).

Comment: You should consider joining SWI-Prolog [Forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) which uses [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/)

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Guy-Coder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dicts in SWI-Prolog have a "tag", which you can use to denote the kind of dictionary as some predicates will only succeed if the tags unify. Examples:

```
point{x: 0, y:0}
json{status: 200, data: [1, 2, 3]}
_{key: variable}
```

To get a value there's three methods, the advantage of using either `get` is that it fails if the key doesn't exist, whereas the more common notation will throw an error if the key doesn't exist.

```
?- _D = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A1']}, A = _D.'I'.
A = ['A1'].

?- _D = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A1']}, A = _D.get('I').
A = ['A1'].

?- _D = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A1']}, A = get(_D, 'I').
A = ['A1'].
```

To set a value there's two methods:

```
?- _D1 = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A1']}, D = _D1.put('I', ['A2']).
D = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A2']}.

?- _D1 = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A1']}, D = put(_D1, 'I', ['A2']).
D = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A2']}.
```

To join dicts is to put one into the other:

```
?- _D1 = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A1']}, D = _D1.put(_{'I': ['A2']}).
D = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A2']}.
```

CapelliC's answer gets you to a point where you have a list of pairs, all grouped correctly, SWI-Prolog provides a useful predicate to go between pairs and dicts:

```
?- _L = [['A1', 'I'], ['A1', 'EU'], ['A2', 'EU']]
|    , findall(B-A,member([A,B], L), _Ps),group_pairs_by_key(_Ps, _G),
|    , dict_pairs(Dict, _, _G).
Dict = _{'EU':['A1', 'A2'], 'I': ['A1']}.
```

Comment: Nice intro to dicts. I preferred not to mention them, because there is (imho) some rough spot in Jan choices when it come down to practical usage.

Comment: I understand, and only use dicts as a bridge to JSON myself. I didn't want to put too much opinion into the answer as per stackoverflow guidelines, but I do understand ;)

Answer (score 4):

library([pairs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs)) offers a ready solution for your problem. Most of the code is needed just to adapt to the format used in the question:

```erlang
?- [library(pairs)].
true.

?- L=[['A1', 'I'], ['A1', 'EU'], ['A2', 'EU']]
|    , findall(B-A,member([A,B],L),Ps),group_pairs_by_key(Ps,G).
L = [['A1', 'I'], ['A1', 'EU'], ['A2', 'EU']],
Ps = ['I'-'A1', 'EU'-'A1', 'EU'-'A2'],
G = ['I'-['A1'], 'EU'-['A1', 'A2']].
```

Comment: Thank you @CapelliC, I have in the end opted to use your solution in my code because I find it more elegant than using a dictionary, but I will accept the answer to Pauk Brown because I find it corresponds more closely to the "intro to dict" that I was looking for. I wish somebody could write an O'Reilly style "Programming Prolog" book. I have been trying to read several books and still "do not get" the essence of Prolog and what it is possible to do.

Comment: The point is that Prolog is really an ancient language (more or less like C), but its original viewpoint make it still interesting despite the numerous advancement done in the meanwhile. Alas, the community didn't found a complete agreement on the standard, so today, there are numerous Prologs incompatible. Indeed, I avoided dicts (also) because they are SWI-Prolog only, while library(pairs) is easily ported to any implementation.